# how to perform OR query with transaction in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

If any single doc exist in `myCollection` in which array contains any value of arr array then I do not wants to add new document in `myCollection2` I want to run this query on cloud function.

**firestore structure**

```
    myCollection
              myDoc1
                  array:[1,2,3]
              myDoc2
              array:[5,8,7]*
   myCollection2 ....
```

---

**How I am doing it**

```
const arr=[2,5,8,9];

return db.runTransaction(async t=>{

  for(let i=0,i<arr.length<t++){
    await  t.get(db.collection('myCollection').where('array','array-contains'arr[i]).then(doc=>{
      if(doc.exists) throw new functions.http.httpError('internal','not available');
    })
  }

  return db.collection('mycollection2').add({
    //fields 
  });

});
```

**is this right approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. What you do is combine different queries which match your terms and combine them. Here is an example using rxjs and typescript

```
function getData(value1, value2)
{
    const scenario1 = this.afs.collection(`collection1`, ref => {
                let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | f 
   firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
                query = query.where("field1", "==", value1);
                return query;

            }).snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(take(1))
                .pipe(
                    map(changes => {
                        return changes.map(a => {
                            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as CustomDataType;
                            data.docId = a.payload.doc.id;
                            return data;
                        })
                    })
                );


    const scenario2 = this.afs.collection(`collection1`, ref => {
                let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
                query = query.where("field1", "==", value2);
                return query;

            }).snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(take(1))
                .pipe(
                    map(changes => {
                        return changes.map(a => {
                            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as CustomDataType;
                            data.docId = a.payload.doc.id;
                            return data;
                        })
                    })
                );
            return forkJoin(scenario1,scenario2)
                .pipe(map((arr) => [...arr[0],...arr[1]] ));
}
```

Comment: It is here in the for loop

Comment: for(let i=0,i<arr.length<t++){
t.get(db.collection('myCollection').where('array','array-contains'arr[i]).then(doc=>{
if(doc.exists) throw new functions.http.httpError('internal','not available');
})
}

Comment: if doc exist then it will throw error stop loop therefor transaction that is what i want is not it?

Comment: This creates 4 observables that are all independent. You will need to find a way to wait for them to be done much like Promise.all() does before further processing. If you console.log, you will find that it your code most likely fires 4 times

Comment: thank you @David .Now i have edited my question with await .is it fine?

Comment: Test it and get back to me

Comment: nice, performing an or operation also had me going WAT for a minute too